# Report Memory exception when running in firebase test lab

Tags: firebase, xcuitest, firebase-test-lab

i am new to XCUI testing and running my test in firebase test lab under its free plan
i am having around 10 XCUI test class files, if i try to run all of my test cases in a single run, the app itself not builded, if i run only a single xcuitest class file by commenting all others, my test cases runs fine

is there any memory limitation there for firebase free plan?

Comment: There's no memory limitation. What do you mean by "the app itself is not builded"? You can join the [Firebase Slack Channel](https://firebase.community/) the team and other users can help you there too.

Comment: EXC_RESOURCE -> FreshsalesUITests-Runner[3011] exceeded mem limit: ActiveHard 1400 MB (fatal)
Apr  3 01:20:34 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: 71066.431 memorystatus: killing_specific_process pid 3011 [FreshsalesUITests-Runner] (per-process-limit 10) - memorystatus_available_pages: 37612
Apr  3 01:20:34 iPhone testmanagerd[227] <Notice>: Test process connection invalidated or interrupted, closing test session <private>.
Apr  3 01:20:34 iPhone testmanagerd[227] <Notice>: Closed <XCTestSession: 0x106302140>, removing from ("<XCTestSession: 0x106302140>")
so its memory issue right?